# File upload struts 2 with Ajax

Tags: struts2, struts

I am uploading a file using struts 2 with jsp as front end, but I dont want to refresh the page after the file is uploaded, so i am using Ajax but with that I am not able to get the File object in action, it seems file upload needs form tag in jsp,and if I am submitting the form then the page gets refreshed.
I researched through the net but cant get many relevant results, it would be of great help if someone guides me through this, is there a way for it. Any help would really be appreciated.
Best regards

Comment: Have tried this example [FileUploadUsingAjax](http://code.google.com/p/ajax-file-upload-struts2/downloads/list)

Comment: these are jar and zip packages,what has to be done can you please guide me what flow is to be adapted?

Comment: @EricIlavia: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270288/upload-file-in-struts2-using-ajax

Comment: @EricIlavia the above link is a good start, which recommends the use of the json plugin, although it isn't 100% required it would be best. The issue mainly client side consider using a proven solution such as: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ which is quite a nice jQuery file upload plugin.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi, please write your comment as answer and ask Eric to mark it to avoid reviewing this question for answer. tnx.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use iframe for upload file instead of ajax,

Sample code for Upload Csv file using struts2 and iframe :

```
    var file = $("#fileUpload").val();
    if(file.indexOf(".") != -1 && file.substr(file.indexOf("."))==".csv"){
        /* created  IFrame  For UPload file*/ 
        var iframe = $('<iframe name="uploadIPAddressIFrame"  id="uploadIPAddressIFrame" style="display: none" />');
        $("body").append(iframe);

        /* Set Form for submit iframe*/
        var form = $('#ipPoolForm');
        form.attr("action", "uploadCSVFile.do");
        form.attr("target", "uploadIPAddressIFrame");
        form.submit();

        openDialog(title);
        /* handle response of iframe */
        $("#uploadIPAddressIFrame").load(function () {
            response = $("#uploadIPAddressIFrame")[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
            $("#chkIPAddressDiv").html(response);
            $("iframe#uploadIPAddressIFrame").remove();
        });
```

After upload if you submit form then change target of form :

```
// Because of  using iframe for upload set target value
$("#ipPoolForm").attr("target", "");
```